# Mysql Server Crash While copying single database using phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, crash, mysqlnd

Im starting a project in Cloud Azure. My machine is a 3.5GB RAM , 30Gb size. 4G os Swap just in case.  Application we run uses mysqlnd server 5.6.28, and Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (preFork).

My database size is around 1GB.

**Problem:**
yesterday i was trying to copy a whole database using phpmyadmin to another name, and all the server starts to slowdown ( the mysql) using around 100% CPU and making my beta users requests to mysql start to lag like hell, and i had to restart the mysql server.

I dont understand what's wrong. I tried to optimize the my.cnf file using percona wizard.

I only have around 3 beta users on that machine, and the number of requests per second is around 15 as my apache server-status says. Can't a 3.5GB , where the allocated to db size is 2GB , accomplish this copy database task!? A simple command...

```
Parent Server Config. Generation: 5
Parent Server MPM Generation: 4
Server uptime: 12 days 19 hours 47 minutes 6 seconds
Server load: 0.25 0.26 0.27
Total accesses: 598877 - Total Traffic: 2.2 GB
CPU Usage: u697.64 s206.04 cu0 cs0 - .0816% CPU load
.54 requests/sec - 2180 B/second - 4033 B/request
10 requests currently being processed, 39 idle workers
.___.WW_W__________________W....W......W..W..._______W_C_W______
__..............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
....................................................
```

this is my.cnf:

```
# The MySQL database server configuration file.

[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve
#skip-locking

#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.

#disabled to allow remote access
#bind-address       = 127.0.0.1
bind-address = 10.0.0.4


#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 256K
thread_cache_size       = 32 

#thread_cache_size=0
host_cache_size=0


# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 800
#table_cache            = 64
thread_concurrency     = 100
join_buffer_size=128

#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 128M
#query_cache_size   = 64M
#query_cache_size   = 128M


#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log


# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
slow-query-log=1
long_query_time = 10
#log-queries-not-using-indexes

#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 7
max_binlog_size         = 60M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name

#
# * InnoDB
#

innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G
#innodb_log_file_size = 2G



 #innodb_buffer_pool_instances=1
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

And on that conf.d folder i have also this one (the percona wizard):

```
#
# The MySQL 5.6 database server configuration file.
#
# This custom MySQL 5.6 specific configuration file
# adds on top of the existing default my.cnf file at
# - /etc/mysql/my.cnf.
# 
# Please add any extra MySQL 5.6 options in this file
# for sake of clarity.
#
# You may uncomment any existing option to enable it
#
# sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES


# Generated by Percona Configuration Wizard (http://tools.percona.com/) version REL5-20120208


[mysql]

# CLIENT #
#port                           = 3306
#socket                         = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]

# GENERAL #
user                           = mysql
default-storage-engine         = InnoDB
#socket                         = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
#pid-file                       = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid

# MyISAM #
key-buffer-size                = 32M
myisam-recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP

# SAFETY #
max-allowed-packet             = 16M
max-connect-errors             = 1000000
sql-mode                       = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
innodb                         = FORCE
innodb-strict-mode             = 1

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql/

# BINARY LOGGING #
log-bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
expire-logs-days               = 14
sync-binlog                    = 1

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 32M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 0
max-connections                = 500
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 4096
table-open-cache               = 4096

# INNODB #
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 128M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 2G

# LOGGING #
log-error                      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log
log-queries-not-using-indexes  = 1
slow-query-log                 = 1
slow-query-log-file            = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

**This is the error log, of a "cron" backup, that also, creates this kind of thing.**

```
2016-04-25 06:42:13 32387 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2016-04-25 06:42:13 32387 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-04-25 06:42:13 32387 [ERROR] Function 'innodb' already exists
2016-04-25 06:42:13 32387 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'innodb' with soname 'ha_innodb.so'.
2016-04-25 06:42:13 32387 [ERROR] Function 'federated' already exists
2016-04-25 06:42:13 32387 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'federated' with soname 'ha_federated.so'.
2016-04-25 06:42:13 32387 [ERROR] Function 'blackhole' already exists
2016-04-25 06:42:13 32387 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'blackhole' with soname 'ha_blackhole.so'.
2016-04-25 06:42:13 32387 [ERROR] Function 'archive' already exists
2016-04-25 06:42:13 32387 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'archive' with soname 'ha_archive.so'.
2016-04-25 06:42:13 32387 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-04-25 06:42:13 32387 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-04-25 06:42:13 32387 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-04-25 06:42:13 32387 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-04-25 06:42:13 32387 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-04-25 06:42:13 32387 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2016-04-25 06:42:13 32387 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-04-25 06:42:13 32387 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 2.0G
2016-04-25 06:42:13 32387 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-04-25 06:42:14 32387 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-04-25 06:42:14 32387 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 2666162556
2016-04-25 06:42:14 32387 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2016-04-25 06:42:14 32387 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2016-04-25 06:42:14 32387 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2016-04-25 06:42:22 32387 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2016-04-25 06:42:22 32387 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 2666163324
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [ERROR] Function 'innodb' already exists
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'innodb' with soname 'ha_innodb.so'.
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [ERROR] Function 'federated' already exists
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'federated' with soname 'ha_federated.so'.
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [ERROR] Function 'blackhole' already exists
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'blackhole' with soname 'ha_blackhole.so'.
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [ERROR] Function 'archive' already exists
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'archive' with soname 'ha_archive.so'.
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 2.0G
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 2666162556
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 2666163324
2016-04-25 19:01:42 35591 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
2016-04-25 19:01:43 35591 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-04-25 19:01:43 35591 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-04-25 19:01:43 35591 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.28 started; log sequence number 2666163324
2016-04-25 19:01:43 35591 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '10.0.0.4'; port: 3306
2016-04-25 19:01:43 35591 [Note]   - '10.0.0.4' resolves to '10.0.0.4';
2016-04-25 19:01:43 35591 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '10.0.0.4'.
2016-04-25 19:01:43 35591 [Warning] 'user' entry 'triconsulte@triconsulte' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2016-04-25 19:01:43 35591 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@beautivmazure' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2016-04-25 19:01:43 35591 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2016-04-25 19:01:43 35591 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.28-0ubuntu0.14.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
2016-04-25 19:01:44 35591 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './beautipt_clean/bea_agenda' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2016-04-25 19:01:44 35591 [Warning] Checking table:   './beautipt_clean/bea_agenda'
2016-04-25 19:01:45 35591 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './beautipt_clean/cms_adminlog' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2016-04-25 19:01:45 35591 [Warning] Checking table:   './beautipt_clean/cms_adminlog'
2016-04-25 19:01:45 35591 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './beautipt_clean/cms_email_logs' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2016-04-25 19:01:45 35591 [Warning] Checking table:   './beautipt_clean/cms_email_logs'
2016-04-25 19:01:46 35591 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './beautipt_clean/cms_siteprefs' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2016-04-25 19:01:46 35591 [Warning] Checking table:   './beautipt_clean/cms_siteprefs'
2016-04-25 19:01:46 35591 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './beautipt_clean/ger_apilog' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2016-04-25 19:01:46 35591 [Warning] Checking table:   './beautipt_clean/ger_apilog'
```

Comment: what tells the errorlog: /var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log. please post the crash

Comment: Not sure why, but i dont have that file.

Comment: in this file writes the server the reason why he crashes

Comment: Well but its empty, i dont have it. When  i go to phpmyadmin, and search for log error it does shows a different path ,  /var/log/mysql/error.log ... Why is this? i thought the value was the my.cnf one.. or the percona wizard...

Comment: you configured that where ever you want or space is. so it can be anywhere, but you can see the path in the config my.cnf

Comment: Right but the my.cnf differs from what phpmyadmin says thats the thing about that path

Comment: I updated my asnwer with the error log, according to the phpmyadmin path

Comment: ok i see the second .cnf file parameter "log-error" is ignored, so the one  in effect is log_error.. why this happens and have different names i dunno.